# What is the purpose of using a JSON text document with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm learning how to use MongoDB with Spring Data in a java application, but I'm trying to decide what's the best way to declare my documents' schema.

The application is going to be a restful web service which accepts JSONs and returns JSONs, and my Java models will obviously determine the properties of those JSONs. It seems like the Java models can determine the "schema" of the MongoDB documents (just make a repository parameterized with, say, User).

However, there is something I'm a little confused about. The [Spring Data MongoDB documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html) mentions under "4.5.3 Repository populators" that you can "define data for the repositories to be populated with" using a JSON text document, but I don't understand what the benefit of that is. How would that help you when you've parameterized your repository with the Java model class?

Comment: Well, guess I answered my own question about updating the "schema." Testing it it doesn't seem to care if you add / remove fields. I'm still wondering what the benefit of the JSON text document is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is mostly used to pre-populate database. You may need pre-population for testing, initializing, etc.

Instead of writing java code to populate your database you can simply keep data in JSON format files. The files are easy to edit and maintain.